# Is compound assignment ^= atomic in C#?

Tags: c#, atomic

I wonder if compound assignment ^= is atomic in C#.
What I really need to do is spin (if the value is 0 then set it to 1 and if it is 1 then set it to 0) an Int32 variable with a single atomic operation.

Comment: For 0 (No/False) or 1 (Yes/True), why use an Int32?! That's exactly what a boolean is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered above, x^=1 is not atomic. Could you use Interlocked.Increment (which is atomic) and then, when reading, consider the value % 2?

Comment: Gold star for you, Rob! It helps me.

Comment: Be careful. "%2" can give you 1, 0 or -1 as an answer. "%2" is not a synonym for reading the bottom bit. If you want to read the bottom bit, read the bottom bit.

Comment: Hadn't considered that. Presumably though, it's not an issue until you overflow.

Comment: @EricLippert for completeness: bool isLSBSet = input & 1 == 1;

Answer (score 3):

Operations guaranteed to be atomic are gathered in the `Interlocked` class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx

Comment: That was my reaction, though it's not immediately obvious to me how to use e.g. CompareExchange to achieve what bsnote wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

Compound assignments are not atomic. `x += 1` for instance is a syntactic sugar for read x from memory, add 1 and write value back to memory.

If you want a good explanation of what is and what is not atomic read Eric Lippert's blog post on the subject: [Atomicity, volatitly and immutability are different](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/26/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-one.aspx)